# My VS Code IntelliSense does not work unless I manually start it with Ctrl + Space

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using JavaScript, which VS Code says is included with IntelliSense.  For whatever reason, the quick suggestions don't work.  If I start typing, nothing shows up.  No suggestions, or anything.  I am running a brand new installation, too (VS Code v1.75.1), and it *should* be working.  I'm running a Windows machine.  I can get it to work when I press ctrl + space, but I don't want to have to do that every time.  I really like being able to hit tab to complete something I can't remember that it recognizes and move on to the next piece of the code.  Having to hit ctrl + space first is a pain.

I've checked all the settings I can find, and it *should* be turned on and it *should* be working.  Oddly, though, there's no "IntelliSense" extension.  I tried looking in the available extensions, and it doesn't exist there, either.  It's almost like my version of VS Code forgot to install it.

I had the same issue when I recently installed VS Code on a Mac device.  I managed to somehow get it to work on there, but I'm not really sure what I did.  I think I tried randomly installing extensions until it worked.

At this point, I have tried looking through settings and all my "Editor: Suggestion" settings are turned on.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the program.  I've tried rebooting my computer multiple times around doing all of these things.  I've added a few other extensions, but they don't work with JavaScript, so nothing really happens.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on or how I might figure it out?

Comment: Show your settings.json file. Did you set `editor.quickSuggestions` anywhere?

Comment: Just saw your other suggestion.  Curiously, my setting for quick suggestions says that "other" is turned on.  However, the settings.json file says it is off.  Changing the file makes it work!

Comment: check both your user settings.json and workspace (`.vscode/settings.json`) files. If you're in a multi-root workspace, check the `.code-workspace` file too.

Comment: Is there a way to default all my changes to the primary .vscode settings?  I don't need separate settings for the user since there's only one user on this device.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. Are you even talking about [workspace settings? or only user settings?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: It looks like this demo workspace comes with settings.  This is something I did not know until you mentioned it.  The workspace settings had it turned off, but my user settings had it turned on.  Now both have it turned on and it is working.  The Prettier extension is not working, though.  It's enabled, listed as default, has a tab space of 2, all of these things for both User and Workspace, but it still does 4.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your question post, your prettier issue is a separate issue and belongs in a separate question post. In general, you should only ask one quesiton per question post.

Answer (score 1):

After some back and forth, the issue was found to be that the workspace settings had set the `"other"` field of `editor.quickSuggestions` to `"off"`, masking the user settings where it was `"on"`. To fix the issue, either remove the `"off"` specification of the `"other"` field from the workspace settings, or set it to `"on"`.

Quoting [the asker's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75417497#comment133154727_75417497):

> It looks like this demo workspace comes with settings. This is something I did not know until you mentioned it. The workspace settings had it turned off, but my user settings had it turned on. Now both have it turned on and it is working.